# When using SVG to create gradient text with a vertical-rl writing mode, the text displays abnormally

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to create vertically oriented text with a right-to-left gradient using the code below. However, the text is being displayed incorrectly.

```css
text {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad-md" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#374151; stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#374151; stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#fff; stop-opacity:0"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text x="50" y="50" fill="url(#grad-md)">测试文本123</text>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the initial few Chinese characters are not displaying correctly, and the direction of the gradient for Chinese text is incorrect.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox. Perhaps you need to report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `text-origination` is `mixed`, which applys differently for different languages. That causes the gradient calculation using different coordinating systems. You can force them to use either `upright` or `sideways` to uniform the calculation (but that means your Chinese will be sideways as well):

```css
text {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-orientation: sideways;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad-md" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#374151; stop-opacity:1"></stop>
            <stop offset="55%" style="stop-color:#374151; stop-opacity:1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#fff; stop-opacity:0"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text x="50" y="50" fill="url(#grad-md)">测试文本123</text>
</svg>
```

However if you just want to apply some gradient to a text, a non-SVG solution might be a better choice:

```css
span {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size: 50px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span>测试文本123</span>
```